# Create an empty promise that just fulfills?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a wrapper that catches the last result of a promise, formats it and outputs the data:

```
req.resolve = (promise) => {
    return promise.then(() => {
            res.json(req.user);
        }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => {
        // respond with validation errors
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors);
    }).catch(err => {
        // every other error
        return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

In one view, I don't have a promise, all that happens is that the auth-function triggers adds req.user and triggers `done()`.

I tried adding a promise like this, but it doesn't get resolved.

```
app.get('/user/me', auth,
    (req, res, next) => {
        req.resolve(new Promise());
    });
```

Comment: What is does `req.resolve()` return without parameter being passed?

Comment: It doesn't return anything, it outputs data to the browser. it has access to a bunch of data in the req-object that is used by express.js

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The `Promise` constructor requires an executor function in its parameter.

If you just need a dummy promise, then you can use `Promise.resolve()` instead of `new Promise()`.

Comment: this works, but I get this warning: Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Comment: Try including `return` statement at `return res.json(req.user);`. What is purpose of nested `.catch()` functions?

Comment: An "empty promise" is another way of saying "a lie" in english.. so having an instantly resolved promise is better, just from a language standpoint ;)

Comment: Promise.resolve() worked for me!

Comment: `new Promise` now requires a parameter, use `Promise.resolve()` instead.