# Returning typed empty promise with typescript

Tags: typescript

My function signature is

```
const jobsByDate = async ( date: string): Promise<Job[]>
```

I fetch the data from BD and return a promise.

If parameter `date === ""` I want to return empty Promise<Job[]>

Something like `return new(Promise<Job[]>)`

So the caller get a promise with empty array of Job[]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiate a resolved promise in ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729403/instantiate-a-resolved-promise-in-es2015)

Comment: Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38078203/1260204

Comment: @Quentin answer is the simple right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions return a promise that resolves as the value given to `return`.

An empty array of `Job` objects is just an empty array. TypeScript can determine that it matches the declared return type of the function.

```
const jobsByDate = async (date: string): Promise<Job[]> => {
    if (date === "") return [];
    // Otherwise return a non-empty array 
}
```